# Names for models for saving

Tags: save

Are there names for the different models for editing and saving data, specifically on a Web form?  What are they?  As examples, there's the model where the user has to explicitly save the data by clicking `Save` or cancel by clicking `Cancel`.  Then there's continuous saving like Google does.  The way JIRA handles editing and saving with an little editors for different elements is another option (though I don't like that you need to hover over them.)  There are probably others.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of some way of classifying the different behaviours, but I don't know if there are 'standard' terminologies for them all. Briefly I think the key elements in the various saving models are:

1. Triggers

   - User driven: the user initiates the saving action (e.g. clicks on save or closes the document)
   - System driven: based on the system picking up changes to the document, or performed periodically (e.g. autosave)
2. Interactions

   - Inline/in-place: the trigger creates an interaction at where the change takes place
   - pop-up/modal: the trigger creates focused area for the user to action/acknowledge
3. Notifications

   - Pre: informs the user before saving
   - Post: informs the user after saving